# What game has this weird 12 sided die with clouds, a bug, a pear and other stuff on it?

Tags: identify-this-game, dice

I found this unusual and hilarious die. I have no clue what it could be from. On the 12 faces I see these 4 particular shapes:

- a lady bug or beetle
- a vest or blouse
- a creepy clown face
- a partly eaten pear

and the rest of the 8 faces are clouds or bats(?)

Can anyone identify this game and help me figure out what this die is actually used for or what the figures really are supposed to represent?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Any individual strange die likely comes from a real game, but the number of games with strange dice is limited. Any individual strange die is _unlikely_ to have been made by a prankster trying to mess with us, but the number of dice such a prankster could make and disseminate is virtually unlimited, and questions about those dice would be unanswerable. It follows that if enough of these questions stay unanswered, the correct answer to most of them probably becomes "you got pranked" :)

Comment: Dang it Google, I don't want to know how to dice a pear... No clue as of yet on what it's for, although they could be charades-like concepts. A food, an emotion, a piece of clothing, and... concepts? So they're thought bubbles?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found it! Through sheer Google-fu, I discovered [ThinkBlot](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/2878/thinkblot)!

[image: ThinkBlot game box and contents]

[Tom Vasel's review](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/6373/user-review) describes its use:

> The game is very simple. Up to six players are given a sheet from a pad included with the game, along with a pencil. Then, the Thinkblot book is opened. It is a spiral bound book that transforms into an Easel with 75 different inkblot pictures, as well as a fold-out scoreboard. Each player places a peg into one of the colored paths on the scoreboard, representing his score.
>
> Now, a special 12-sided die is rolled. Instead of numbers, there are little pictures or blots on each side of the die. Depending on what is rolled, the players write down things on their scoring sheet that they think they see in the inkblot currently showing. Whenever a little blot is rolled (eight of the twelve sides), players write down anything they see in the inkblot mess. When a little bug is rolled (one side), players should write down any creature they see in the picture. When a little face is rolled (one side), they are to write down people, parts of people, or actions taken by people. When a half eaten pear is rolled (one side), players should write down any food they see. And when a little shirt is rolled (one side), players are to write down any clothing or accessory they see.

Comment: I had serious doubts about them being clouds. They'd've probably made the die black and the spots white if that was what they wanted. Now it makes sense!